# Must I fix all TS errors before Angular production build?

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, production

I am able to run my Angular v8 app in development mode even there are <s>TSlint</s> TS errors (just showed few at below). However, when I try to build for production, it failed with `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2`. I have a number of <s>TSlint</s> TS errors, is there a way to build for production without fixing these errors?

```
ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.ts:16:3 - error TS2564: Property 'closeResult' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

16   closeResult: string;
     ~~~~~~~~~~~

ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/module/home/search.component.ts:24:40 - error TS2339: Property 'kendoDatePicker' does not exist on type 'JQuery<any>'.

24     $(this.datePickerEl.nativeElement).kendoDatePicker({
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main/webapp/app/module/home/search.component.ts:25:16 - error TS7006: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.

25       change: (e) => {
                  ~
src/main/webapp/app/module/home/search.component.ts:74:43 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

74     console.log("type :" + JSON.stringify(this.model.selectedRefIdObj.id));
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 2
    npm ERR! ent-app@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--profile"`
```

*Update:*

Thanks htn for his solution for jQuery. Tested is working. Another solution is

```
declare const $: any;
```

FYI, I am using [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) 6.7.1, and here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "strict": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "target/classes/static/app",
    "lib": ["es7", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["src/main/webapp/app/*"]
    },
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src/main/webapp/app", "src/test/javascript/"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/main/webapp/app/module/webrtc/"]
}
```

Here is my `tsconfig-aot.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "strict": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "target/classes/static/app",
    "lib": ["es7", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["src/main/webapp/app/*"]
    },
    "importHelpers": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "target/classes/aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": true
  }
}
```

`webpack.prod.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'production';
const sass = require('sass');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    // Enable source maps. Please note that this will slow down the build.
    // You have to enable it in Terser config below and in tsconfig-aot.json as well
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('target/classes/static/'),
        filename: 'app/[name].[hash].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
            loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { implementation: sass }
            }],
            exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: '../'
                    }
                },
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: { implementation: sass }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: '../'
                    }
                },
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader'
            ]
        }]
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                parallel: true,
                cache: true,
                // sourceMap: true, // Enable source maps. Please note that this will slow down the build
                terserOptions: {
                    ecma: 6,
                    ie8: false,
                    toplevel: true,
                    module: true,
                    compress: {
                        dead_code: true,
                        warnings: false,
                        properties: true,
                        drop_debugger: true,
                        conditionals: true,
                        booleans: true,
                        loops: true,
                        unused: true,
                        toplevel: true,
                        if_return: true,
                        inline: true,
                        join_vars: true,
                        ecma: 6,
                        module: true
                    },
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                        beautify: false,
                        indent_level: 2,
                        ecma: 6
                    },
                    mangle: {
                        module: true,
                        toplevel: true
                    }
                }
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: 'content/[name].[contenthash].css',
            chunkFilename: 'content/[id].css'
        }),
        new MomentLocalesPlugin({
            localesToKeep: [
                    'en',
                    'ar-ly',
                    'zh-cn',
                    'ta'
                    // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-moment-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
                ]
        }),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'static',
            openAnalyzer: false,
            // Webpack statistics in target folder
            reportFilename: '../stats.html'
        }),
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
            mainPath: utils.root('src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts'),
            tsConfigPath: utils.root('tsconfig-aot.json'),
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: false
        }),
        new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
            clientsClaim: true,
            skipWaiting: true,
            exclude: [/swagger-ui/]
        })
    ],
    mode: 'production'
});
```

`webpack.common.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('base-href-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MergeJsonWebpackPlugin = require("merge-jsons-webpack-plugin");

const utils = require('./utils.js');

module.exports = (options) => ({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        mainFields: [ 'es2015', 'browser', 'module', 'main'],
        alias: utils.mapTypescriptAliasToWebpackAlias()
    },
    stats: {
        children: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: true,
                    caseSensitive: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes:false,
                    minifyJS:false,
                    minifyCSS:false
                },
                exclude: /(src\/main\/webapp\/index.html)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    digest: 'hex',
                    hash: 'sha512',
                    name: 'content/[hash].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /manifest.webapp$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'manifest.webapp'
                }
            },
            // Ignore warnings about System.import in Angular
            { test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\].+\.js$/, parser: { system: true } },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: `'${options.env}'`,
                BUILD_TIMESTAMP: `'${new Date().getTime()}'`,
                // APP_VERSION is passed as an environment variable from the Gradle / Maven build tasks.
                VERSION: `'${process.env.hasOwnProperty('APP_VERSION') ? process.env.APP_VERSION : 'DEV'}'`,
                DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: options.env === 'development',
                // The root URL for API calls, ending with a '/' - for example: `"https://www.jhipster.tech:8081/myservice/"`.
                // If this URL is left empty (""), then it will be relative to the current context.
                // If you use an API server, in `prod` mode, you will need to enable CORS
                // (see the `jhipster.cors` common JHipster property in the `application-*.yml` configurations)
                SERVER_API_URL: `''`
            }
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/*.{js,css,html,png}', to: 'swagger-ui', flatten: true, ignore: ['index.html'] },
            { from: './node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js', to: 'swagger-ui' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/', to: 'swagger-ui' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/content/', to: 'content' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp', to: 'manifest.webapp' },
            // jhipster-needle-add-assets-to-webpack - JHipster will add/remove third-party resources in this array
            { from: './src/main/webapp/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt' }
        ]),
        new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
            output: {
                groupBy: [
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/en/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/en.json" },
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/ar-ly/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/ar-ly.json" },
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/zh-cn/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/zh-cn.json" },
                    { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/ta/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/ta.json" }
                    // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
                ]
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
            chunks: ['polyfills', 'main', 'global'],
            chunksSortMode: 'manual',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
        new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/' })
    ]
});
```

`utils.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

const tsconfig = require('../tsconfig.json');

module.exports = {
  root,
  mapTypescriptAliasToWebpackAlias
};

const _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [_root].concat(args));
}

function mapTypescriptAliasToWebpackAlias(alias = {}) {
  const webpackAliases = { ...alias };
  if (!tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths) {
    return webpackAliases;
  }
  Object.entries(tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths)
    .filter(([key, value]) => {
      // use Typescript alias in Webpack only if this has value
      return Boolean(value.length);
    })
    .map(([key, value]) => {
      // if Typescript alias ends with /* then remove this for Webpack
      const regexToReplace = /\/\*$/;
      const aliasKey = key.replace(regexToReplace, '');
      const aliasValue = value[0].replace(regexToReplace, '');
      return [aliasKey, root(aliasValue)];
    })
    .reduce((aliases, [key, value]) => {
      aliases[key] = value;
      return aliases;
    }, webpackAliases);
  return webpackAliases;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not TSLint error but typescript compilation error. For this error, you should set `strictPropertyInitialization` to `false` in your `tsconfig.json` (and `tsconfig.app.json`)?

Edit: It is bad but you can also disable other flags like `strict` to false.
You should never do it, but if it helps you, you can use: `@ts-ignore` to ignore errors. However, if you have to ignore too many errors, stop using Angular

For `$(this.datePickerEl.nativeElement).kendoDatePicker`, the correct way is to declare `kendoDatePicker` method for jQuery. And the fast way to ignore error:

```js
($(this.datePickerEl.nativeElement) as any).kendoDatePicker(...)
```

You can declare `$` as any, but you are losing the type of jQuery ==> You don't have the benefit of using Typescript anymore. Anyway, using jQuery in a Angular project is usually bad ...

This is an error only with `noImplicitAny` flag setting to true. I don't see it in your tsconfig.json. Anyway, try to add `noImplicitAny: false`

```
src/main/webapp/app/module/home/search.component.ts:25:16 - error TS7006: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.

25       change: (e) => {
```

This is an error only with `strictNullChecks` flag setting to true. I don't see it in your tsconfig.json. Anyway, try to add `strictNullChecks: false`

```
src/main/webapp/app/module/home/search.component.ts:74:43 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

74     console.log("type :" + JSON.stringify(this.model.selectedRefIdObj.id));
```

You can also try to set `fullTemplateTypeCheck` to false.

Anyway, it is bad to disable these flags, try to learn typescript and write  clean code.

Comment: Note though that this can lead to erros during runtime, which is exactly what TypeScript is supposed to guard against. Better solution would be to either assign a value in the constructor or declare the variable with `closeResult?:string;`, telling the compiler that the variable can be `undefined`. Although this may show you further errors, as you now need to guard against the variable being `undefined`.

Comment: You are right, but it is not always a good choice with Angular: an `@Input()` property may be `undefined` on the constructor, but always defined for the lifetime of the component. It would be heavy to check the property each time you use it.

Comment: In that case, you can also use `closeResult!: string;` to assure the compiler that the variable will definitely be assigned, even if you're not doing so during declaration or inside the constructor. IIRC Angular also recommends this in the documentation of the Input decorator, or at least did this when I read it.

Comment: Why in development mode, these errors can be ignored? I tried your solution but still have issue. My error is not only `has no initializer` but other types as well (updated my errors). How to force webpack to totally ignore errors that are okay in development mode?

Comment: @CGundlach that's right. That's what I use. However, when you are arriving to a project with many cases like this, it is better to disable this option. And you can slowly activate it from time to time to fix error. In my case, I activate `strict` option, but only in dev.

Comment: @htn Yeah, in that situation that's alright. Although the last time I arrived at a project like this where an unexperienced team worked on an Angular project and was annoyed by these errors when the code was clearly working, I created a branch to fix all these issues and worked on it for a week, after talking about it in the first SCRUM meeting after getting acquainted with the code.

Comment: I set both `strict` and `strictPropertyInitialization` to `false` in my tsconfig.json and tsconfig-aot.json, but still the same error. Any other solution?

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json`? @LeeCheeKiam

Comment: Sorry for late reply due to different timezone. Updated in question.